# Translate Code from JAVA to C#, Socket Streams

Tags: java, c#, sockets, stream

I have a Java code that I have to convert to C#. The code is very basic, includes streams and sockets.

Java Code:

```
    Socket fg = new Socket("localhost", 5400);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reg_flight.csv"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fg.getOutputStream());
    String line;
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
        out.println(line);
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    fg.close();
```

I was able of course to convert the first line, but I'm having trouble finding in Google a way to output line by line via Sockets. Specifically: `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fg.getOutputStream());`.

My C# start:

```
TcpClient s = new TcpClient("localhost", 5400);
NetworkStream stream = s.GetStream();
StreamReader input = new StreamReader("reg_flight.csv");
StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(stream);
String line;
while ((line = input.ReadLine())!= null) {
      Console.WriteLine(line);
      output.Write(line);
      output.Flush();
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
 }
```

For some reason, this is not working (the server doesn't receive the data correctly). I've printed the line inside the while loop and the reading seems correct. What could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code conversion service and there's plenty more research you could do before asking a question about this. The class and method/property names are different in .NET but that's about 98% of it. The algorithm doesn't change, and you should use `using` blocks on the reader and writer instead of calling `Close` explicitly. You're already using `StreamReader`. Take a look at  `StreamWriter`, as well. Beware of the output encoding, too. That should be explicit, not defaulted or detected like the Java code has done.

Comment: @madreflection I've edited the question with the code I wrote, seems to me that it should be correct. The server is not receiving the data though

Comment: That's definitely an improvement on the question. So few people actually take the attempt further, so kudos to you. At first glance, `output.Write` should be `output.WriteLine` to match `out.println`. As for why it's not being received, that's probably going to require some debugging details.

Comment: why is there a sleep ?

Comment: Because the server is taking the data to make an image out of it, and then show it as a video. The wait is for the smooth video visualization. I removed the flush and it's now working!